# What is "active" in flag summary?

Tags: support, flags

I've flagged a post about 2 days ago and on my flag summary it now has an orange "active" mark.

[image]

Any insights on what this is?

Comment: I wonder if this is [a delayed flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112501)?

Comment: @ick That request doesn't seem to be implemented. I'm curious about this too.

Comment: I've flagged 600 things, and never seen this.

Comment: I also have a few flags and never seen this before. at first I thought it means that a moderator is currently reviewing it however it's there for quite some time now..

Comment: Seeing it on SO now. Might have to flag this to see it on Meta.

Comment: The duplicate question wasn't answered too.. anyone?

Comment: I'm seeing this a lot on regular Stack Overflow now

Comment: @YotamOmer The duplicate has since been answered.

Comment: @ColeJohnson don't know if the answer was there before :)

Comment: @YotamOmer probably wasn't... Well, you could now delete this and relinquish the 15 rep from it, or you can keep it if you want